# Plot function of x, y as the colour density on a scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Say I have a list of heights that a measurement were taken from:

```
[0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5, 8.0, 8.5, 9.0, 9.5, 10.0, 10.5, 11.0, 11.5, 12.0, 12.5, 13.0, 13.5, 14.0, 14.5, 15.0, 15.5, 16.0, 16.5, 17.0, 17.5]
```

And I have a 2d list of angles that the data were taken from (from off vertical),

```
[[], [20, 50], [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 320, 330, 340, 350], [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 330, 340, 350], [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 310, 320, 340], [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 300, 310, 330, 340, 350], [0, 20, 30, 50, 60, 70, 310, 320, 330, 340, 350], [0, 10, 20, 40, 110, 320, 330, 340, 350], [0, 10, 20, 150, 300, 310, 320, 330, 340, 350], [0, 10, 20, 140, 180, 190, 310, 320, 330, 340], [10, 20, 30, 40, 150, 180, 340], [0, 140, 180, 320], [130, 140, 180, 190], [130, 180, 190], [190, 200], [180, 190], [170, 180, 190], [160, 170, 180, 190], [150, 160, 330, 340], [160, 170, 190, 350], [170, 190], [170], [190], [180], [160], [340], [20, 30, 40, 290, 330], [0, 20, 40, 60, 340], [], [], [], [0], [10, 20, 200, 230, 290], [10, 180, 190, 200, 210, 240, 340, 350], [30, 220]
```

(set of lists correlates to the heights in the first list, so blank entries mean no measurements were taken at the corresponding height). I want to plot the angle on the x axis, and the height on the y axis. However, for each point, I also want to plot a slope that has been calculated earlier (not the slope of the previous two lists). This slope list is in the exact same format as the list of angles, and I would like to plot it as a colour density. The slopes are generally between -1 and 1, and they show the correlation. I am essentially searching for the slope of two variables, per angle, per time.

This is what I have so far, but am having trouble figuring out how to plot the slope.

```
for x in range(0, len(height)):
    height_temp = np.linspace(height[x], height[x], len(angle[x]))
    plt.scatter(angle[x], height_temp, s = slope[x])
plt.show()
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need:

```
plt.scatter(angle[x], height_temp, c=slope[x], s=slope[y], cmap='rainbow')
```

You're probably going to want to consider setting vmin and vmax as well.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am just a bit confused as to what the variable 'y' is?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know what the other variable was that you wanted to relate to size. You may need to use a multiplier with your s variable, depending on the values. for my purposes, I end up with s = 600 to give you an idea of the vicinity you might need to be in.

Comment: ah. I want each "marker" to be the same size, as eventually there will be thousands of points . Should i just exclude the "s = ..." then?

Comment: Possibly. You'll want to see how it looks. You'll probably also want to evaluate if you want the points to be outlined in black or not. In an older version of MPL, black lined was the default, but it isn't any more. It will depend on what version you're running.

Comment: Okay I will keep it as is for now, and evaluate later when there is more data. Thank you very much!

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept / upvote the answer :)